# How do I change the appearance of Eclipse IDE? (To white)

Tags: eclipse

i am running **Eclipse Version: 2020-03 (4.15.0)** and I want to change the too small fonts and the black background to **white**: but I can't find the, normally simple configuration items.

> Eclipse->Prereferences->Appearance->Color and Fonts

. There is a list of several "Active/NoActive" entries and it either is not clear where to set a simple background color or it is not present in that configuration.
Also on the "Window" tab there is no entry for customizing the appearance. Although there is a "contextual help" under the "Help"-tab, and, ironically, the help-system shows the Editor with normal readable black-on-white-background, it would not reveal anything how to customize the editor to the shown view.
(I´ve already searched for a solution but no one were adequate)

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime, I found the solution: it seems as if the only way to change the theme of the editor is (somehow logical if you know it) to right-click IN the editor window and there in the "Preference->Appearance" tabs I can choose easily between some different color themes. And the "Light Linux" color theme with classical Color and font theme give a useful and readable combination.